# How to access a struct member when iterating a vector of structs with vector::operator[]

Tags: c++

I want to access "line_number" in the Line struct's token_list. Why does `token_line_number = line.token_list[i+i].line_number;` return '1' instead of '2'? I include two different ways I can get to '2' but I would like to undersand why my first code fragment returns '1'.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    struct Token
    {
        std::string text;
        int line_number;
    };
    struct Line
    {
        std::vector<Token> token_list;
    };
    Token token;
    Line line;

    token.text = "A";
    token.line_number = 1;
    line.token_list.push_back(token);
    token.text = "B";
    token.line_number = 2;
    line.token_list.push_back(token);

    int token_line_number = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if ( i + 1 < line.token_list.size() )
    {
        token_line_number = line.token_list[i+i].line_number; // <-- I want this to be '2'. Instead it is '1'.
        Token token = line.token_list[i+1];                      
        token_line_number = token.line_number;                // This is '2'.
    }
    token_line_number = 0;
    std::vector<Token>::const_iterator iter;
    if ( iter + 1 != line.token_list.end() )
        token_line_number = (iter + 1)->line_number;          // This is '2'.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change the value of `i` here, so it is `0`:

```
int i = 0;
if ( i + 1 < line.token_list.size() )
{
    token_line_number = line.token_list[i+i].line_number; // i has not been changed from 0
```

Remember that `0+0` is `0`. So `line.token_list[i+i]` is `line.token_list[0]`.

Comment: Oh gosh, I am so sorry. I have been staring at this for so long I didn't notice that it was not i + 1. That was foolish. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma why not use ++i anyway and drop the +1 thereafter? Or, better yet, if you are on c++11 why not use for(const auto& token: line.token_list) ?

Comment: @emaster I simplified the code. In our application we need to "look ahead" at the next token while still keeping track of the current token, hence do not want the side effect of ++i. We use MSVS 2010 and so do not have the full complement of c++11. Am unsure if auto is available. I'm using [] because the actual application uses pointers vs. iterators. My real problem (truly) is I need a new prescription. :)